# Initialise list container objects within a struct using C++?

Tags: c++, list, struct, char

I have a struct that contains three lists and an integer as can be seen in the code below.

```
struct MainScreenState 
{
    std::list<char*> sessionId;
    std::list<char*> opposingUser;
    std::list<char*> currentMove;
    int totalScore;
    MainScreenState() {
        totalScore = 0;
    }
};
struct MainScreenState *state;
```

To initialise an int is possible using a constructor, but how do you initialise the list objects so that you avoid the compiler warning "warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'state'".

Comment: Get rid of all those pointers, they have almost no place in C++. `char*` => `std::string`. The `state` doesn’t need to be a pointer anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::list` members are automatically initialized. The problem is with the variable `state`, which is un-initialized.

```
MainScreenState *state = NULL; //struct keyword not necessary in C++
```

or (per request)

```
MainScreenState *state = new MainScreenState;
```

or prefer using automatic-storage variables or a smart pointer.

Comment: I didn't mean you should allocate a MainScreenState. I just mentioned that since I usually prefer 0(or nullptr) rather than NULL, but well, you should use what you prefer :D.

Comment: @mfontanini `nullptr` is only for C++11. `0` is for numbers :).

Comment: @mfontanini same as NULL can be for numbers :P

Comment: You you should try to convince Stroustrup that "0 is for numbers": http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#null. And no, using NULL as a number is not the same as using 0 for pointers. That is one of the main reason why the NULL macro can't be defined as nullptr.